# Android AlarmManager not Triggering

Tags: android

I'm just trying to get a simple test app working with AlarmManager.

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {
    private static final int PERIOD = 1000;

    private AlarmManager alarmManager;
    private PendingIntent pendingIntent;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.v("TextActivity", "WHY NOT!");

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.test);

        alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, TestReceiver.class);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                System.currentTimeMillis(), PERIOD, pendingIntent);

        Log.v("TestActivity", "Whee!");
    }
}

public class TestReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.v("TestReceiver", "Got Here");
    }
}
```

I have tried this on both a hardware phone and the emulator and I am not seeing the messages received. Am I missing something obvious? I am relatively new to Android development.

Comment: Have you declared the receiver in the manifest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you register your receiver in AndroidManifest.xml? Also period is milliseconds, so that alarm will trigger every second, is this really what you want?

Comment: Yeah, its just to test for now. I did not know you had to add to the manifest. I will check that out.